# get token from API Login Response and pass to API header request Header of other Menu in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, api, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms iOS and I want to get token value after Login.

I have read documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/authentication-and-authorization
But I don't know where to start, to apply in my code.

This is what I did so far. (response login worked)

**Response body after successfully logged in:**

```
{
  "message": "Login success",
  "token": "2|yQa9L51Fo1OpMx8zJSK2AegnDVJWjacJ6IbfEE2e",
  "store_id": 1
}
```

**APIResponse.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace App88.Models
{
    public class APIResponse
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string token { get; set; }
        public int store_id { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**HttpHelper.cs**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using App88.Models;

namespace App88.Helpers
{
    public class HttpHelper
    {

        public async Task<APIResponse> callAPI(string url, string json)
        {
            APIResponse res = new APIResponse();
            try
            {
                string content = string.Empty;
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = null;
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
                {
                    httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                }
                else
                {
                    var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);

                }

                if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(content);
                }
                else
                {
                    res.message = "Invalid Response";
                }

                return res;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                res.message = ex.Message.ToString();
                return res;
            }
        }



    }
}
```

**LoginViewModel.cs**

```
using App88.Helpers;
using App88.Models;
using App88.Views;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App88.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ICommand btnLogin { get; set; }
        private UsersModel _users { get; set; }

        private string _message { get; set; }
        public string message
        {
            get
            { return _message; }
            set
            {
                _message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public UsersModel users
        {
            get { return _users; }
            set
            {
                _users = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool _isActivity { get; set; }

        public bool isActivity
        {
            get { return _isActivity; }
            set
            {
                _isActivity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            users = new UsersModel();
            users.email = "";
            message = "Please enter your credentials to proceed";
            btnLogin = new Command(async () => await userLogin());
        }

        private async Task userLogin()
        {
            try
            {
                string webURL = APIHelper.loginAPI;
                HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper();
                isActivity = true;
                APIResponse res = await httpHelper.callAPI(webURL, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users));
                isActivity = false;
                if (res.message == "Login success")
                {
                    LoginResponseDetails details = new LoginResponseDetails();
                    string obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
                    details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponseDetails>(obj);

                    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Dashboard(details));

                }
                else
                    message = res.message;

                isActivity = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isActivity = false;
                message = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

**VMDashboard.cs**

```
using App88.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace App88.ViewModels
{
    public class VMDashboard : BaseViewModel
    {

        private LoginResponseDetails _loginResponseDetails { get; set; }

        public LoginResponseDetails loginResponseDetails
        {
            get { return _loginResponseDetails; }
            set
            {
                _loginResponseDetails = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public VMDashboard(LoginResponseDetails detail)
        {
            loginResponseDetails = detail;

        loginResponseDetails.message = detail.message;
        loginResponseDetails.token = detail.token; //token value successfully landed here!
        loginResponseDetails.store_id = detail.store_id;
    }


}
```

}

API Documentation in Postman.

[image: Get Procurement List]

I want to get previous User Login response token and make it authorization header in GET Procurement List. Kindly help to enlighten what is missing/wrong.

Comment: If you want to use it in every request, then I would just store it in the HttpHelper class.  There is no need to propagate it up into the VM each time

Comment: @Jason: by adding new Task? Could you give a simple example?

Comment: No, just have your existing method save the token.  It would probably be best to make HttpHelper a singleton, or at least make the token property static.  It’s too late here for me to provide an example, maybe tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Xamarin.Essentials to save `Token` value on login success response. Please get its value like below, when ever you need it to pass in header.

The Preferences class helps to store application preferences in a key/value store.

To save a value:

`Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value");`

To get a value:

`var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");`

Refer to know more about preferences: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android

Hope this helps.!